# Terminology - the & of 3

Tags: terminology, rhythm

I found myself telling someone to accent "the & of 3". This just seems a really awkward way of wording it, but I don't know a better way. Beat 3 and half or the 6th 8th note sound even worse.

Is there proper terminology for the positions between the beats?

Answer (score 2):

"The & of 3" is proper terminology and is very specifically tied to how you would count out the music. A very similar alternative you could say is "the offbeat of 3" which means the same exact thing as "the & of 3". You could also say the following, but they are much more wordy:

- Halfway between 3 and 4
- An eighth note after 3

Comment: In conducting, the upbeat is the last beat of a bar. Bars have upbeats but beats themselves don't. For this reason I don't agree that "the upbeat of 3" does mean the same as "the & of 3". But I think the other explanations you gave are fine.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS good catch.  I actually ment the offbeat of 3. Will fix now.

Comment: "3 and" or "and before 4" would be the most intuitive for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of a pretty common set of terminologies used to communicate sub-beat patterns.  These are, for the case of X/4 time sigs:

a) quarter notes:   one, two, three,...
b) eighth notes:   one-and, two-and, three-and
c) triplets:  one-and-ah, two-and-ah
d) sixteenths  one-eee-and-ah, two-eee-and-ah,
e) quintuplets:  you're on your own :-)

For any of these patterns, the composer may have indicated emphasis on one or more of the on- and off- beat notes.